# Python print number lines and line from text file

Tags: python

Im trying to read lines from a text file and print the number of the line and the line next to the number

Ive tried using enumerate but I want to find another way of doing it

the file contains :

```
pizza
hello
goodbye
```

I want to print to the screen

```
1-pizza
2-hello
3-goodbye
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Comment: `enumerate` is the cleanest way to do it. I can think of other ways, but enumerate is the simplest.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Duplicate: [Printing out each line (from file) with line number python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197657/printing-out-each-line-from-file-with-line-number-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple for loop over the file:

```
lineCounter=0
with open('C:/t.txt') as readObj:
    lines=readObj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')
        lineCounter += 1
        print('{}-{}'.format(lineCounter,line))
```